# How to get the URL of the current page in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httprequest, .net-7.0

In the new .NET 7.0 framework, things have changed considerably...
This has been asked a gazillion times before and if the .NET Core framework would not break all kinds of backwards compatibility then I would have an easy answer. Too bad a lot of answers are related to .NET 4.9 and older and they just don't work.
So in my minimal Web API I want to do some simple request logging by sending the complete URL as a string to a database. (With some additional information.) So I have the [HttpContext class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0) (NOT the [HttpContext class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8.1)) with the [Request property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.request?view=aspnetcore-7.0) of [type HttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and it just does not have any method to get the original URL that was requested. Only the various parts which I have to concatenate and hope it resembles the original uri...

So, a useful method like Request.Url is now totally gone and the [DisplayUrl helper()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.getdisplayurl?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-extensions-urihelper-getdisplayurl(microsoft-aspnetcore-http-httprequest)) isn't providing me everything. It leaves out the QueryString. I need that QueryString also.
And yes, I can concatenate this again to get the value that it originally received and made hidden. It just feels wrong, though. Plus, this method makes the uri suitable to be returned in a header. Again, I want to store it in a database for logging purposes exactly as it originally was!
So now I have to ask something that has been asked a gazillion times before, simply because the latest .NET update breaks things again.

The application I'm working on is a multi-tenant application running on multiple domain names including wildcard subdomains and is used to analyze the amount of traffic I get for new domains that I've registered. The whole API will just generate 404-errorcodes back to the user, but I want the whole URL to get registered to determine if the domain isn't getting any funny requests. (Like hackers trying to access https://owa.example.com/wp-booking.php or https://forum.example.com/default.aspx?g=rsstopic&pg=0&ft=0 or whatever.) I also log the body of the request, the request method, the IP address of the user and the headers that are passed and it cal be used by me to extend a blacklist of users who seem to have malicious intent.
The domains where I use it are often fresh out of quarantine and are just in a wait-state until development starts. (Or until someone takes it over.) Responding with a 404-error should tell users (and hackers) that the site does not exist any more. Most users will be aware that the site is gone so they stop visiting, but various automated (and hacking) tools might still be running so the information tells me what the user is trying to do.
Anyways, I need the full URL with the query string, domain name, protocol and everything else that the client has passed to my server. But .NET 7 is preventing me from access to the original URL which is dumb. And the whole project is basically a single [app.Run() statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) which always returns a 404 error after logging the request. And yes, slow is fine for this API.
*Sigh*... [Request.Url.AbsoluteUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.absoluteuri?view=net-7.0) was such a useful function, but it's gone, making all answers going back 14 years or so obsolete as Request has no Url...

Comment: `HttpContext` class has `Request` field, which is of `HttpRequest` type. And that `HttpRequest` class has a lot of various fields (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which could be useful for you. Did you try that?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps...You mention that you want this for request logging, and I think they're making that a first class citizen now? I see middleware for it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?source=recommendations&view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Based on source code `GetDisplayUrl` [should return query string also](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/UriHelper.cs,214).

Comment: @GuruStron Yeah, it's just that the MSDN documentation was unclear about it. It contains the words: "except for the QueryString" so I expected the QueryString to be omitted. In reality, the QueryString stays encoded while the rest is not... :)

Comment: @Nikki9696 Nope, not very useful in my case, but still useful some some, I think. The ILogger interface is a bit overkill for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl`([source](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/UriHelper.cs,214)) should do the trick:

```cs
app.MapGet("test_uri", (HttpContext context) => context.Request.GetDisplayUrl());
```

Returns `http://localhost:5207/test_uri?query=1&test=2` for this url.

> So in my minimal Web API I want to do some simple request logging by sending the complete URL as a string to a database.

Minimal APIs support request logging - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75029363/net-core-7-minimal-post-body-logging/75031240#75031240). Potentially you can combine it with some logging library which allows writing to database.

Comment: Weird, as MSDN says: "The combined components of the request URL in a fully un-escaped form (except for the QueryString) suitable only for display."
This suggests to me that the URL has been sanitized. But now I realize the QueryString stays encoded while the rest is not. :)

Comment: @WimtenBrink yes, this is about encoding url, not about query string not being included in the result. But I agree, wording is not perfect.